# Is it possible to use googletrans to only translate whats between marked areas?

Tags: python, google-translation-api, google-translator-toolkit

Trying to develop something that can auto translate things into different languages in a file but only want things to translate between marked areas. Question is: Can I specify .read to only read between lets say ""?

In my file I have a list of sentences or words or lets even say letters and they are there sitting. I put "" speech marks around the sentence or a word I want to translate.

Down below is my txt file:

```
Sentence 1 - "I like Bannannas and I will eat them all day."
Sentence 2 - How is your day going?
Sentence 3 - "Will there be any sort of fun today or just raining?"
Sentence 4 - Can the sun come out to play!!!
```

I want to be able to translate the sentences which are now only wrapped around the "".

My Code Currently:

```
import re
import googletrans
from googletrans import Translator

file_translator = Translator()

tFile = open('demo.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8")

if tFile.mode == 'r':
    content = tFile.read()
    print(content)

result = file_translator.translate(content, dest='fr')

with open('output.txt', 'w') as outFile:
    outFile.write(result.text)
```

Comment: What do you mean by marked area? Can you describe it with some examples? Is marked text is in file and how did you marked it?

Comment: Okay so lets say I got a list of sentences that I want to translate in a txt file. I mark the sentences I want to translate with in lets say "The sentence is located here between the 2 speech marks and I want to only translate what's in the speech marks and nothing else."

Does this help?

Comment: I don't understand what is speech mark but if you provide example data or some kind of same data what you want to translate then yeah! It is definitely possible! And try to give data and explanation in question not in comment!

Comment: Ama try explain it easier. In my main question with a few examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first we have go find the right sentence in the file, so for that we used `re` to find the text and then we have to translate that text using `googletrans` and then we have to replace the found sentences with translated sentences and finally we can write the whole paragraph in text file.

Here's the code to do all those stuff:

```
import re
import googletrans
from googletrans import Translator

file_translator = Translator()

with open("demo.txt","r") as f:
    content=f.read()

pattern=re.compile(r'"([^"]*)"',re.MULTILINE)
founds=re.findall(pattern,content)

translated=[]
for found in founds:
    translated.append(file_translator.translate(found, dest='fr').text)

for f,t in zip(founds,translated):
    content=content.replace(f'"{f}"',t)

with open('output.txt', 'w') as outFile:
    outFile.write(content)
```